# Apache startup script keeps lock file open

Tags: 14.04, bash, apache2, backup, lock

I am writing a bash script for a backup task. Among other things (file system freeze, database lock, snapshots,...) it involves shutting down Apache and restarting it after the Backup. Since that script should be run as a cronjob and execution times may vary largely (especially since the script waits for a "good moment" to take the Backup), I tried to protect it from multiple executions using `flock`.

However, `flock` keeps the lock even after the backup script exits. This behavior is independent of the way I use `flock` (use a directory, a file or a file descriptor opened from within the script).

I hunted the problem down to the restart of apache2 and can see it in the following one-liner

```
flock -n /var/lock/startapache service apache2 start
```

See the following interactive session to illustrate the problem:

```
root@fermat:/home/ubuntu# service apache2 stop
 * Stopping web server apache2                                                                                                                  ... waiting .                                                                                                                          [ OK ]
root@fermat:/home/ubuntu# flock -n /var/lock/startapache service apache2 start || echo failed
 * Starting web server apache2                                                                                                          [ OK ] 
root@fermat:/home/ubuntu# flock -n /var/lock/startapache service apache2 start || echo failed
failed
```

That's because the started Apache script keeps my lock file descriptors open:

```
root@fermat:/home/ubuntu# lsof /var/lock/startapache 
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
apache2 23651 root    3u   REG   0,17        0 6673997 /run/lock/startapache
apache2 23656 trac    3u   REG   0,17        0 6673997 /run/lock/startapache
apache2 23674 trac    3u   REG   0,17        0 6673997 /run/lock/startapache
apache2 23675 root    3u   REG   0,17        0 6673997 /run/lock/startapache
apache2 23676 root    3u   REG   0,17        0 6673997 /run/lock/startapache
apache2 23677 root    3u   REG   0,17        0 6673997 /run/lock/startapache
apache2 23694 root    3u   REG   0,17        0 6673997 /run/lock/startapache
apache2 23696 root    3u   REG   0,17        0 6673997 /run/lock/startapache
```

Once I shutdown Apache, the lock is freed again:

```
root@fermat:/home/ubuntu# service apache2 stop
 * Stopping web server apache2                                                                                                                  ... waiting                                                                                                                            [ OK ]
root@fermat:/home/ubuntu# flock -n /var/lock/startapache service apache2 start || echo failed
 * Starting web server apache2
```

**Therefore my question(s):** How does the Apache process "inherit" those file descriptors? Why doesn't the same behavior occur with other startup scripts (e.g. "service mysql start")? And is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 or older, I guess? Mysql is managed by Upstart which ensures a clean environment for started services. Apache is managed by a sysv init script (`/etc/init.d/apache2`). Being a shell script, it inherits everything (environment variables, open file descriptors, etc.), and the an apache process started by it will inherit all of those as well.

Comment: @muru: Thank you for the comment! Even though not a complete answer, this was the only helpful comment. Write it down as an answer, if you are interested in the bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since nobody wrote an answer (despite bounty), I'm going to explain myself, how I finally solved this.

*muru*'s comment (thanks a lot!) was right and brought me on the right track: In Ubuntu 14.04, the Apache startup is managed by a sysv init script, and being a shell script it inherits everything (environment variables, open file descriptors, etc.), and the apache process started by it will inherit all of those as well. Mysql, in turn, is managed by Upstart, which ensures a clean environment for started services. This explains the different behavior for Mysql and Apache.

Armed with that knowledge I knew better, what to look for, and found [this answer on unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/143904). It suggests to close the file descriptor in the sub-shell that calls scripts that shouldn't inherit it, while keeping the descriptor open in the outer shell, to make sure that the lock stays effective.

Unfortunately, this means that I had to move the `flock` calls to within the shell script, otherwise my script wouldn't know which file descriptor to close. So my new shell script (which also took some inspiration from [this blog post about `flock`](http://www.kfirlavi.com/blog/2012/11/06/elegant-locking-of-bash-program/)) has the following structure:

```
#!/bin/bash

FLOCK_FILE="/var/lock/backup-lock"
FLOCK_FD=20

# Locking
eval "exec $FLOCK_FD>'$FLOCK_FILE'"
if ! flock -n $FLOCK_FD
then
  echo "FAILED! There is a backup script already running."
  exit 1
fi

(
  # Unlock in sub-shell, so daemons with bad startup scripts
  # (like Apache) don't inherit the look.
  # Note that the lock is still alive in general because it's
  # held by the outer shell.
  eval "exec $FLOCK_FD>-"


  # ... normal backup stuff from the original script ...

  # Among other stuff the mentioned vicious line:
  service apache2 start

  # ... normal backup stuff from the original script ...
)

# Unlock in outer shell because we're done.
eval "exec $FLOCK_FD>-"
```

Comment: That's why I didn't post an answer. I couldn't find a clean way to close the fds. :(

Comment: To avoid hard-coding a file descriptor, you can get the lowest-numbered unused one by:  Replace [FLOCK_FD=20] with the 2 lines [exec {FLOCK_FD}>"$FLOCK_FILE"] and [exec {FLOCK_FD}>&-].  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297415/in-bash-how-to-find-the-lowest-numbered-unused-file-descriptor